Unreachable Service: youtubePartner
I have taken over a simple program running on Google App Scripts that was utilizing the YouTubeContentId service. It seems now that this service has become unavailable to me.
When running the program, I get an error stating that youtubePartner is unreachable in the Execution log:
Execution log -
Unreachable Service: youtubePartner

I also tried removing and re-adding the service (listed as "YouTubePartner" with identifier "YouTubeContentId") and I get the same error in a different place:
Error Notification - Unreachable Service: youtubePartner

The script was utilizing:
YouTubeContentId.ClaimSearch
YouTubeContentId.AssetSearch
YouTubeContentId.ContentOwners

Was this service removed from Google Scripts? Or maybe the functionality was moved into a different service?

Please add a [mcve].

Have you activated the YouTube Content ID Service in the GCP project that is linked to your Apps Script?
This link explains how to enable the YouTube Content ID service:
Enable advanced services

That, as it is, should rather be a comment. If you want to leave it as an answer, please elaborate; see "Provide context for links".

I have reached out to YouTube and it was determined to be an issue with their API. This has now been resolved.
